# Inserting dictionary to heap Python

Tags: python, dictionary, heap

I'm trying to build a heap with (key, value) so the key is a number and the value is a dictionary.

```
import heapq
heap = []
dic = {'val_1': 'number_1', 'val_2': 'number_2', 'val_3': 'number_3'}
insetToHeap = (2,dic)
heapq.heappush(heap, insetToHeap)
```

The code crashes on `heappush`. The element probably not in the right format.

EDIT:

The error is:

> TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()

What is the right way to insert to heap the (number, dic) elements?

Thanks.

Comment: okay, then you need to include the traceback and expected output (and explain what "crushes" means).

Comment: Are you sure that **the example you posted** throws that exception? I can't see a way that this would compare dictionaries because the `heap` is empty.

Comment: No error is raised when this code is run

Comment: Please show us your full code for help.

Answer (score 10):

Dictionaries can't be ordered, so you need to create something that can keep the dictionary but doesn't use it in comparisons.

Tuples are not a good choice because every element in them **might** be compared. For example if the first element (your `key`) is equal then the second item is compared:

```
>>> (1, {'a': 1}) < (1, {'a': 2})
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
```

Or with `heap`:

```
>>> heap = []
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (2, {'a': 1}))
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (2, {'b': 2}))
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
```

If the `key` is garantueed to be unequal then there's no problem because the second item won't be compared.

In case you just want some storage for the `dict` you could simply create a class that stores `(key, value)` but only ever compares the `key`:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class KeyDict(object):
    def __init__(self, key, dct):
        self.key = key
        self.dct = dct

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.key < other.key

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.key == other.key

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0.__class__.__name__}(key={0.key}, dct={0.dct})'.format(self)
```

Insert these into your `heap` and this will garantuee that the `dict` won't be compared:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heap = []
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, KeyDict(2, {'a': 1}))
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, KeyDict(2, {'b': 2}))
>>> heap
[KeyDict(key=2, dct={'a': 1}), KeyDict(key=2, dct={'b': 2})]
```

---

An alternative is to use 3 tuples using a counter as second element that garantuees the comparison won't go to the dict:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> cnt = count()
>>> heap = []
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (2, next(cnt), {'a': 1}))
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (2, next(cnt), {'b': 2}))
>>> heap
[(2, 0, {'a': 1}), (2, 1, {'b': 2})]
```

Comment: using a class is better as it is clear. The alternative solution would be hard to maintain...

Answer (score 0):

`dict` instances cannot be compared in Python 3:

```
>>> {'a': 9} < {'a': 10}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

which means neither can your tuples if the first elements are equal:

```
>>> (2, {'a': 9}) < (3, {'a': 10})
True
>>> (2, {'a': 9}) < (2, {'a': 10})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
>>>
```

You need to ensure that the `dict`s themselves never need to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a bit of testing and even though you didn't show your full code it would seem that your code is pushing to the heap more than one `dict`.

```
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (0,dic))
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (0,dic2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
```

Your heap is comparing the dictionaries because the first item of the list has been compared and so it proceeds to compare the next item, instead you need to do something like:

```
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (0,dic))
>>> heapq.heappush(heap, (1,dic))
>>> show_tree(heap)

(0, {'val_1': 'number_1', 'val_2': 'number_2', 'val_3': 'number_3'})
(1, {'val_1': 'number_1', 'val_2': 'number_2', 'val_3': 'number_3'})
------------------------------------
```